# How can I have a HashMap with unique keys in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I have a HashMap with unique keys in Java?
Or even does this make any sense to have unique keys in HashMap or the keys are unique by default?
I am a newbie.
thx

Comment: Keys _are_ unique by default. Note that `.keySet()` on a `Map` returns a `Set`, and elements of a `Set` are unique by default. If you attempt to push a value to an existing key, the old value will be overwritten.

Comment: note that "unique" in java means equal in terms of implementation of the methods equals and hashcode!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The keys are unique in all maps. The difference between the various maps implementations concern the possibility of null keys, the order of iteration and concurrency issues.

Answer (score 61):

Hash map key is unique. Add duplicate key, then it will be overwritten.

```
 HashMap hm = new HashMap();
 hm.put("1", new Integer(1));
 hm.put("2", new Integer(2));
 hm.put("3", new Integer(3));
 hm.put("4", new Integer(4));
 hm.put("1", new Integer(5));// value integer 1 is overwritten by 5
```

By default Hashmap is not synchronized.

Comment: so how do we make the key value relationship not unique,i.e,i want also the value 5 for the key 1 above ?Is there any method to serve that purpose

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh, you will have to store some sort of `List` or `Map` for that corresponding `key`. `Map<String, List<Integer> m = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at the [Java API for Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) which is interface that `HashMap` implements. The first sentence is:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

Answer (score 1):

HasMap has unique keys. as .keySet() returns Set which has unique members

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is a collection to store (key,value) pairs and According to the documentation of [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) the keys are always unique.

If you add a key which already exists(collision) in the hashmap, the old value will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

A generic hashmap is usually implemented as an associative array, so let's say your array has N elements, from 0 to N-1, when you want to add a new (key, value) pair, what it's done behind the scenes is (just conceptually):

1. index = hash(key) mod N
2. array[index] = value

So, by construction, a key is mapped to one and one only array entry.

Please note that it's actually a bit more complex than this: I am ignoring on purpose things like collision handling, rehashing, etc, you may have a good general idea here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table